# How to add custom method to Spring repository?

Tags: spring, methods, repository, spring-data-jpa

Currently, here is my way to add custom method to one Spring Repository:
- firstly, create 1 interfaces extended from JPARepository along with my interface like this

```
interface MyRepository extends extends JpaRepository<Model, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Model.class>, MyRepositoryCustom
```

then to create MyRepositoryCustom interface and its implementations

```
intefaces MyRepositoryCustom{
     void myMethodHere();
}

class MyRepositoryImpl implement MyRepositoryCustom {

   void myMethodHere(){
    // do somethong
    }
}
```

The problem is now that I want to reduce the amount of class, so is there any way to add custom methods with only 1 interface and 1 implement class.

Comment: This question needs spelling correction to understand it

Comment: If I understand correctly the issue, then you can reuse the custom implementation `MyRepositoryImpl` class for every repository you want. Just add `MyRepositoryCustom` interface to that repository and spring will automatically use the implementation class `MyRepositoryImpl' for custom methods. No need to create new interface and class for same custom method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the same custom method for all repositories in your app you have to:

1. Create base Repository interface by extending Repository Interface
2. Implement method in base Repository interface
3. Implement Custom `RepositoryFactoryBean`
4. Specify custom `RepositoryFactoryBean` in `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation in configuration.

More details, for example, you can find here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/

Comment: It's not really what I want. I just want to add some method to specific repositories. But the number of repositories now is to large. So in the mean time, I want to remove some classes.